# Navigation same width as body

Tags: html, css

I have the following code which contains a navigation bar as well as a "Welcome" message placed on top of a video. My issue is that I'm wanting the navigation and video to both ideally be the same width and both be completely centered within the page horizontally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/metagamepfp.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css">
        <script src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
        <title>MetaGameVGC</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <nav class="main-nav">
         <ul>
            <li>
               <a class="current" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="pages/articles.html">Articles</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="pages/teamreports.html">Team Reports</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="pages/teamcompendium.html">Team Compendium</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="pages/resources.html">Resources</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="pages/events.html">Events</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
      <section class="welcome">
          <video playsinline autoplay muted loop>
            <source src="videos/pokemon-gym.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support this video tag.
          </video>
          <span class="welcome-message">WELCOME TO METAGAME!</span>
      </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the current CSS. As you can see, I'm looking to set the width of the video to 980px, and I cannot figure out how to get the navigation to match the width of the video as well.

```
/* Navigation Bar Style */
nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.main-nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.19vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.main-nav li {
    display: inline;
}

.main-nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    color: black;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 1vw;
    padding-top: .75vh;
    padding-bottom: .5vh;
    padding-right: 4vw;
    transition: background-color .25s linear, color .25s linear;
}

.main-nav a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    transition: background-color .25s linear, color .25s linear;
}

.main-nav .current {
    background-color: black;
    color: #ff2c7b;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

.current::before {
    content: "";
    border: 12px solid black;
    border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -12px;
}

/* Styling for Welcome */
.welcome {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 3vh;
}

video {
    max-width: 980px;
    height: auto;
    padding-left: 1vw;
}

.welcome-message {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 4vw;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px){
.mainWrapp {max-width:912px;  margin: auto;}
}


.welcome video {
  width:100%;
    height: auto;
   
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Would you mind clarifying more on why you have a set width for the mainWrapp? Also, how did you decide on those values?